# pandas - extract numbers between set of varying characters with varying position

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm wondering how can I extract numbers between set of varying characters with varying position in a column.

I'm trying to extract all the numbers after the string 'FC=' until the next non number character (number might be negative as well).

**Sample df code:**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'W': ['abcde','abcde','abcde']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['First']=[0,0,0]
df['Last']=[1,2,3]
df['Slice']=['abFC=0.01#%sdadf','12fdak*4%FC=-0.035faf,dd43','FC=0.5fasff']
```

**Sample df:**

```
       W  First  Last                       Slice
0  abcde      0     1                   abFC=0.01
1  abcde      0     2  12fdak*4%FC=-0.035faf,dd43
2  abcde      0     3                 FC=0.5fasff
```

**Desired output:**

```
       W  First  Last  Slice
0  abcde      0     1  0.01
1  abcde      0     2  -0.035
2  abcde      0     3  0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`pd.Series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Slice'] = df['Slice'].str.extract(r'(?<=FC=)([\d\.\-]+)')
```

Yields:

```
       W  First  Last   Slice
0  abcde      0     1    0.01
1  abcde      0     2  -0.035
2  abcde      0     3     0.5
```